# How can I add a custom option to the Microsoft Edge context menu?

Tags: python, registry, microsoft-edge, contextmenu

I just found out about using the Registry Editor to add a custom option that runs a custom Python script to the right click menu in Windows Explorer, and I'm hoping for a way to do a similar (or ideally the same) thing with the right click menu for text in Microsoft Edge (or super ideally the right click menu for all text in all programs, but it really seems like that much isn't possible).

I can see microsoft-edge in the Registry Editor, but I'm avoiding doing anything with that until I know it's safe.

I'm currently hoping to do this in order to be able to append text from a webpage to a certain text file (or alternatively to the clipboard) right from Edge, but knowing how to do that via a custom Python script would allow me to do more in the future.

The closest I've found is a little extension for Edge that I can't download because it has an invalid signature or something.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you're using Edge Chromium. If so, you need to use [Edge extension API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/api-support) `contextMenus` to add items to the context menu in Microsoft Edge. You can refer to [this doc](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/) for detailed information about the API.

There's an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-right-click-menu/onnbmgmepodkilcbdodhfepllfmafmlj/related?hl=en-US) which can achieve your goal. You can add it in Edge by clicking on 'Add to Chrome'. I've tested it in Edge Version 89.0.774.68 and it can work well.